# Exception Error in Window Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, mobile

I installed succesfully all the WP7 tools and created a very basic application but when it comes to debug. The WP7 phone Emulator fails with Exception from HRESULT:0x89721800. The same error appear when try to load the Emulator directly. Any ideas any one? ive already uninstalled and re=installed from the main MS WP7 page but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN forums ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/fde4c415-44c5-4837-b1cd-e09727a75b92/)):

1. Try setting VS2010 to launch as Administrator: Make sure you are logged in as Administrator. Right click on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone, choose Properties, click on the Compatibility tab and turn on the check box for "Run this program as an Administrator". Relaunch Visual Studio (logged in as Administrator).
2. Here's another suggestion from a Microsoft developer who reported similar problems that he fixed on several occasions by following these steps:

Close the solution and then delete the solution .suo file and/or the project .user file.
Reopen and see if the deployment works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic error message. I would recommend:

1. Restart the PC.
2. Create a new project, don't change anything, and try running it.
3. Uninstall then reinstall the lot from scratch, including the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

The steps below worked for me.

If you get error code 0×89721800 when attempting to deploy to your phone device, this typically indicates that the Visual Studio datastore is corrupt. Here are a couple of workarounds:

Workaround #1

1. Close all Visual Studio instances that may be currently running.
2. Delete the folder “%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\10.0”
3. Launch a new instance of Visual Studio

Workaround #2

The above error code has also been reported when Windows Mobile 5x or 6x emulators are installed in the system. Try uninstalling them both.